# UPDATE SQL with Session

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am trying to insert image path into an existing databse. The code below works, but inserts a new row.

```
$address= htmlentities($_SESSION['address']);
$city= htmlentities($_SESSION['city']);
$zip_code= htmlentities($_SESSION['zip_code']);

        $query =
          "INSERT INTO  property(name, size, type_picture, file_path, username) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        $conn = $db->prepare($query);
        if ($conn == TRUE) {
            $conn->bind_param("sisss", $myfile, $fileSize, $fileType, $path, $username);
            if (!$conn->execute()) {
                echo 'error insert';
            }else {
                echo 'Success!<br/>';
                echo '<img src="' . DISPLAY_PATH . $myfile . '"/>';
            }
        } else {
            die("Error preparing Statement");
```

When I try the same as above but UPDATE, i get the "Error preparing Statement". I need to update empty cells (if this matters).

```
$query =
   "UPDATE  property(name, size, type_picture, file_path, username) 
    SET(?,?,?,?,?) 
    WHERE address = '$address'  // with or without ''
          city = '$city' ";
$conn = $db->prepare($query);
            if ($conn == TRUE) {
                $conn->bind_param("sisss", $myfile, $fileSize, $fileType, $path, $username);
                if (!$conn->execute()) {
                    echo 'error insert';
                } // etc. etc.
```

Thank you so much. Tried for a day, need some help.

Comment: Updates has absolutely nothing to do with sessions.

Comment: Also, this site is not about help. It is about answering questions.

Comment: It is about help. Could id downvote comments i would downvote your both.

Comment: Why are you calling `htmlentities` on these strings? That is only useful when displaying the string in an HTML context and has nothing to do with your database calls. Also you've completely omitted proper SQL escaping on `$address` and `$city`. These should be using placeholders like the other parameters. You've created a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: @T_01 please read site rules. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update query is wrong, try this instead:

```
$query = "UPDATE property SET name = ?, size = ?, type_picture = ?, file_path = ?, username = ?
WHERE address = ? AND city = ?"
$conn = $db->prepare($query);
            if ($conn == TRUE) {
                $conn->bind_param("sisss", $myfile, $fileSize, $fileType, $path, $username,$address,$city);
                if (!$conn->execute()) {
                    echo 'error update';
                } 
             }
```

Comment: Well, I got a new error now and I am happy about that. "error insert" Let me work on that. Thank you!

Comment: Yep, there was a mistake in my code (change and change...), not your code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You need an `AND` or `OR` in the `WHERE` statement:

```
WHERE address = '$address' AND // with our without ''
      city = '$city' ";
```

I also don't think you should mix parameters with string substitution.  Make `$address` and `$city` parameters as well.

Comment: I am sorry, I had the AND in my original code, than I removed one variable, them i just tried where id = 1, nothing works with the update. I need to try above answer. Thank you.